# mongodb on server (jboss and glassfish) doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, servlets, jboss7.x

I am using Eclipse Kepler, Java, Jboss 7.1 and Mongodb.
When I am trying to send request from the Servlet to the class that works with the Mongodb I get an exception:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.conversions.Bson`

I am including the org.bson to the prohect by importing jar file named mongo-java-driver-3.0.3.jar.

The code is really basic and simple:

```
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import org.bson.Document;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
    import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

    public class UserConnection {
        private MongoClient client;
        private MongoDatabase md;
        private MongoCollection<Document>userCollection;

    public void initUserConnection(){
        client=new MongoClient();
        md=client.getDatabase("eatFreeLottery");
        userCollection=md.getCollection("users");
    }
    public void addClient(){
        Document d=new Document();
        d.append("name", "Sam");
        this.initUserConnection();
        userCollection.insertOne(d);
    }
```

Servlet:

```
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    UserConnection uc=new UserConnection();
    uc.addClient();
}
```

Main class:

```
    public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserConnection uc=new UserConnection();
    uc.addClient();
}
```

}

Both the servlet and the class work fine as long as they don't need to work together.

At first I thought that the problem was with my glassFish server so I switched to Jboss, but that got me nowhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  You need to provide some more details; examples would include the snippet of code that is making the request, and how you are including org.bson.* (e.g. do you have a jar file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.
Just copy paste the Jar file (mongo-java-driver-3.0.3.jar) under the web-inf/lib  of the project and it works.